# How does one trust third party certificates in VMware vCenter 6.5?

Tags: vmware-vcenter

I have an vCenter 6.5 server and a Content Library named `iso`. I'd like to import CentOS 7.4 from https://mirror.us-midwest-1.nexcess.net/CentOS/7.4.1708/isos/x86_64/CentOS-7-x86_64-Everything-1708.iso. But when doing so, the import fails with the following error:

`A general system error occurred: The import of library item ff47df87-2352-4714-a321-7d2cdc699999 has failed. Reason: InternalServerError (com.vmware.vapi.std.errors.internal_server_error) => { messages = [LocalizableMessage (com.vmware.vapi.std.localizable_message) => { id = com.vmware.vdcs.cls-main.error_while_transferring_from, defaultMessage = Error transferring file CentOS-7-x86_64-Everything-1708.iso from https://mirror.us-midwest-1.nexcess.net/CentOS/7.4.1708/isos/x86_64/CentOS-7-x86_64-Everything-1708.iso. Reason: Server not trusted: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target, args = [CentOS-7-x86_64-Everything-1708.iso, https://mirror.us-midwest-1.nexcess.net/CentOS/7.4.1708/isos/x86_64/CentOS-7-x86_64-Everything-1708.iso, Server not trusted: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target] }], data = <null> }.`

The server https://mirror.us-midwest-1.nexcess.net/ has a Commodo certificate. Other download sites use Let's Encrypt certificates.

How does one add the root certificates and intermediate certificates of these certificates authorities to vCenter so that I can download ISO images from the internet?

I have been looking at documentation and can't find any documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I havn't tried this but maybe you can add root CAs via [vecs-cli entry create](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/6.5/com.vmware.psc.doc/GUID-80C30209-028D-4F92-9551-CDB6B25A8403.html) to TRUSTED_ROOTS.